# insert in database with column number

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to insert in a table using columns order not name

```
insert into tableName(1,2,5) values('val1','val2','val3');
```

i dont want to use

```
insert into tableName values('val1','val2','val3');
```

because the table does not contain just 3 columns

how can i do it

because columns name are encrypted  so I can not rely on this

```
insert into  tableX("cCGSvKJVQXnt8A==","aDOlOQrPfg==","qsdcx112")
values('val1','val2','val3');
```

is there any idea  how can i  deal with this

thank

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the question is how can i do it

Comment: Why not name? `INSERT INTO table(firstname,lastname,age)` is much more readable.

Comment: Why can't you use column names?  In reality there's no such thing as a stable column "number".

Comment: because they are not visible characters they are encrypted

Comment: Absolutely the field names should be used.  Even if you could specify by column number that would be a horrible design decision, as you would then need to potentially update your code if you ever made a schema change to add new columns.

Comment: You can not do this based on column name alone via SQL.

Comment: Wait, why the crap are your table names unprintable characters?  That's a terrible design decision.  There are much better ways to protect your database schema from being discoverable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the ordinal number of a column in an insert statement.  However, you can accomplish what you're trying to do (insert values into specific columns in a table) using the column names instead.

Presume your table has five columns; I'm going to call them "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", and "Echo", since you haven't given us the schema for your table, but replace these names with the names of the columns actually in your table.  I'm guessing that your third and fourth column (my "Charlie" and "Delta") are nullable.  You can then insert a tuple/row in your table with the other three columns filled using syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(Alpha, Bravo, Echo) VALUES ("val1", "val2", "val3");
```

If, per your comments above, your column names are unprintable characters (which is a terrible, *terrible* idea), you can explicitly insert NULLs into the missing columns:

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES ("val1", "val2", NULL, NULL, "val3");
```

but the weakness here is that, if additional columns are subsequently added to your table's schema, the insert statement will start failing.

Comment: so what happens to the columns that already have a default value   they will be null either

Comment: You can use the DEFAULT keyword to explicitly specify the default value for a column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the column names where you have the 1,2,5. You can't use the column number.

```
insert into tableName(1,2,5) values("val1","val2","val3");
```

Comment: the name of columns is encrypted  so i can not